# Merge methods that return an empty set and an empty list

Tags: generics, kotlin

These two functions are very similar

```
fun <T> emptyList(): List<T> = emptyList<T>()

fun <T> emptySet(): Set<T> = emptySet<T>()
```

Is there some way they could be combined into a single method which returns either an empty set or an empty list? If the caller has to pass the empty collection to be returned, that would be fine.

Ideally I would like to achieve this without the caller needing to resort to casting, i.e. using `as` or `is`.

Comment: "If the caller has to pass the empty collection to be returned, that would be fine." If they already have this collection on hand, why do they need a method returning it? `fun <T> (x: T) = x` would work in this case, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: `fun <T> empty(): Collection<T> = empty<T>()`

Comment: @QingfeiYuan I think you mean `emptyList` or `emptySet` in that expression at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to return two types as the same time. You **have to** determine it somehow.

### From a `List` or a `Set`

You could create an [extention function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) that create an empty collection from an existing one.

```
fun <T> List<T>.empty() = emptyList<T>()
fun <T> Set<T>.empty() = emptySet<T>()
```

From that you can use it like any other list/set function.

```
val emptyList: List<Int> = listOf(1,2).empty()
```

Be careful. It do not transform the current list. It just create a new one empty.

### From an unknow collection like `Iterator`

A pure Iterable that has no upperclass:

```
fun <T> empty() = object : Iterable<T> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<T> = object : Iterator<T> {
        override fun hasNext(): Boolean = false
        override fun next(): T = throw IllegalStateException("No Item")
    }
}
```

You can use the already defined function [`Iterable.toSet()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-set.html) and [`Iterable.toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html)

```
val emptyList: List<Int> = empty<Int>().toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface which implements both `List<E>` and `Set<E>`:

```
interface ListSet<out E> : List<E>, Set<E> {
    // Must override this fun because it's defined in `List` and `Set`
    override fun spliterator(): Spliterator<@UnsafeVariance E>
}
```

Now you can return its instance from your function:

```
private object EmptyListSet :
    ListSet<Nothing>,
    List<Nothing> by emptyList(),
    Set<Nothing> by emptySet() {
    override fun spliterator(): Spliterator<Nothing> = emptyList<Nothing>().spliterator()
    // Must override following elements because they can be delegated to `List` and `Set`
    override val size: Int get() = 0
    override fun contains(element: Nothing) = false
    override fun containsAll(elements: Collection<Nothing>) = false
    override fun isEmpty() = true
    override fun iterator() = emptyList<Nothing>().iterator()
}

fun <E> emptyListSet(): ListSet<E> = EmptyListSet
```

Use cases:

```
val list: List<Int> = emptyListSet()
val set: Set<String> = emptyListSet()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

fun main() {
    val emptyList = emptyCollection(List::class)
    val emptySet = emptyCollection(Set::class)
}

fun <T: Collection<*>> emptyCollection(clazz: KClass<T>): Collection<Nothing> {
    return when (clazz) {
        List::class -> emptyList<Nothing>()
        Set::class -> emptySet<Nothing>()
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```